# Does a move action used as a failed attempt to escape an effect (through a failed check) provoke an attack of opportunity?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, opportunity-attack, saving-throw, move-action

This is a magical effect that I am able to get in our Pathfinder 1e game.

> Any hostile creature must succeed on a Reflex save any time it becomes
> or starts its turn adjacent to you. A creature that fails its save
> cannot move away from you without first succeeding on a Strength check
> or an Escape Artist check against your sphere DC made as a move
> action.

The basics of it are pretty easy to understand. Creature becomes adjacent and must make a reflex save. If failed then it must succeed at a strength check or or Escape Artist check to move away from me.

My question is, if a creature attempts to move away from me in a way that would provoke an AoO but fails its check, does that still provoke an AoO from me? I can't find clarity in the rules. This [Actions in Combat table](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/Combat/#Table-Actions-in-Combat) doesn't have anything that covers this and I can't find anything elsewhere. There are various things under the Move Action section but none of them are quite right, and the Escape a Net action is kinda similar but not the same (and it is a full-round action) so I don't know that it would apply here either.

I could see it both ways. If the creature fails it check then it doesn't move away so no AoO. But it is using a move action to attempting to move away, and the AoO for moving away happens before actually moving away, so I could also see it the other way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## You don't have to move to escape entangling locks

A creature that's affected by the the [**entangling locks**](http://spheresofpower.wikidot.com/fallen-fey#toc12) ability (that's hair not keys or canals) can take a [**move action**](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/Combat/#TOC-Move-Actions) (but not actually travel any distance) to make a Strength check or an Escape Artist skill check (DC = your sphere DC). Failure means that the creature can't move anywhere but adjacent to the foe with the entangling locks ability. Success means that the creature can move normally until its again affected by the entangling locks ability.

However, although success means that the creature *can* move away from its foe with the entangling locks ability, the creature hasn't done that yet. It must still take a move action to move using its speed so that it exits the [**threatened area**](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/Combat/#TOC-Attacks-of-Opportunity) of the foe with the entangling locks ability before it'll provoke from that foe for that movement. If it does, though, then the foe's attack against the creature will occur *before* the creature travels to the space that caused it to provoke.

The difference is that, in that second case, *the creature will move* to its selected new position on the battlefield unless an attack of opportunity or other effect prevents the creature from doing so. When the creature took a move action to free itself from the entangling locks ability, it didn't try to move to a new position on the battlefield.

The entangling locks ability must say that the creature's act of taking a move action to make the check provoked an attack of opportunity for that act to provoke an attack of opportunity. Just being able to move isn't moving.

Answer (score 3):

## No, it has to move to provoke.

The [rules on attacks of opportunity](https://www.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Attacks%20of%20Opportunity&Category=Combat%20Statistics) are pretty clear:

> Two kinds of actions can provoke attacks of opportunity: **moving out of a threatened square** and performing certain actions within a threatened square.
>
> *Moving*: Moving out of a threatened square usually provokes attacks of opportunity from threatening opponents. There are two common methods of avoiding such an attack—the 5-foot step and the withdraw action.

They didn't move out of a threatened square, so they do not provoke an attack of opportunity for doing so.

Unless you have an ability that provides an attack of opportunity for them failing to move, you would not receive one.